# HTML Strict validation is not recognizing my imported documents?

Tags: html, validation, xhtml, w3c-validation

I am just validating my webpage and working through the errors. the scenario I have is that I have the structure where I import a header file, through `<?php include ('header.php') ?>` and also with my navigation file. Now in terms of seeing it in the browser this works, but when I validate with XHMTL1.1 strict it comes up with the error.

So I have an index.php which imports both the header.php and navigation.php - now as I am writing this I am realizing that the navigation.php does not get the css file imported into it, but does the validator not just read the html? so there it should pick it up and see that it gets the information?

Please let me know if I am on the right track with this, otherwise it seems that you sacrifice validation for a structured website??

Cheers Jeff PS Happy New Year:-)

EDIT CODE:

> URI: http://thepalmsmarket.co.nz/index.php    a
>   276   9     there is no attribute "id"  a
>   276   24    there is no attribute "class"   a
>   276   38    element "nav" undefined

I these are the last errors and they are related to this code:

index.php:

```
<?php include_once ("01includes/header.php"); ?>

</head><!--hmtl tag closes in the footer--> 

<body class="no-js"><!--The script here is to disable the class put into the body tag if javascript is enabled.--> 
<?php include_once ("01includes/navigation.php"); ?>
```

navigation.php:

```
<nav id="topNav" class="centeredmenu">  
<ul>
    <?php
        $subject_set = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM webMenu", $dbconnect);
        if (!$subject_set) {
        die("Database query failed: " . mysql_error());
        }
        while ($subject = mysql_fetch_array($subject_set)) {
        echo "<li class=\"{$subject["class"]}\"><a href=\"   {$subject["link"]}\" onclick=\"{$subject["javascript"]}\" title=\"{$subject["title"]}\">{$subject["menuItem"]}</a></li>"; }
    ?>
</ul>
```

The css is declared in desktop.css which is imported into header.php, but not into navigation.php as that would be a double up - hope that makes sense:-)

Comment: Are you attempting to validate the output HTML individually (what each script outputs) or a complete version of what is rendered in the browser? Could you paste some examples here, as well as the specific validation error?

Comment: I am validating the whole end document - I will update my initial post with information. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good news: nothing to do with PHP. You appear to be using the `nav` tag, which is new in HTML5, while validating against the XHTML 1.1 Strict.  If you switch to an HTML5 declaration, so that you can use  `nav` in a nice, valid, semantic way, then you'll have to chase down a few other validation errors (mostly related to the meta tags, and then use of a deprecated `border` attribute further on in your code -- the validation errors should be self-explanatory).  If you want to keep on with XHTML, then drop the use of  `nav` to be valid.

Comment: cool - thanks for that, I noticed that I did used that just before your answer but had not quite come up with an alternative yet:-) I'll work out form here;-)